# Add standard Romanian keyboard with diacritics to Gboard

Tags: keyboard, languages, gboard

Is it somehow possible to install a [Gboard keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin&hl=en&gl=US) layout for Romanian that has the diacritics  `ă â î ș ț` as separate keys? [Other keyboard apps have it](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/78019/romanian-virtual-keyboard-layout-with-special-characters-for-android),

[image]

but not Gboard.

The ones that are called Romanian and can be added in settings are exactly the same as the English ones, where those diacritics can be typed as special characters under `a i s t`.

The layouts that are available for Romania in Gboard are generic, e.g.QUERTY, while other keyboard apps that do have the layout I ask for here are displaying it as a specific sub-type,   for example  in [Flesky](https://www.fleksy.com/) keyboard app it's caled "QWERTY (Romanian)".

[image]

In [Multiling O Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kl.ime.oh&hl=en&gl=US) it is called "Romanian standard", like in Linux.

Answer (score -1):

There's something called "Vlax Romani (Romania)" for Gboard that looks mostly like the screenshot example you have. I guess that's a specific dialect of Romanian (according to Google, at least -- I know next to nothing about the language), but it looks like it could work for your purposes... unless the auto-correct and spell-check are so different that they drive you nuts.